# Does the Vimeo Unity SDK allow Vimeo livestreams to display in my Unity App?

Tags: vimeo

Im interested in using the Vimeo Unity SDK to display Vimeo livestreams in our app. We plan to have the app built both for Unity WebGL and Mobile.

Can someone confirm if this is possible using Vimeo Unity SDK? I know it allows for uploaded videos to be streamed, but does it also allow for livestreams to be displayed?

Thanks!

Comment: Checkout the GitHub SDK page .. https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-unity-sdk - under Streaming Features it is stated that they support both. The plugin also supports AVPro Video which supports both as well. Now I played around with that stuff about a year ago and did some drone live streaming right into Unity but not through Vimeo Live but my own setup which worked without issues. I don't think you will have any big issues. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 

For the applications we have in mind, it is important that we find out if Vimeo livestreams can be displayed in our Unity App. Hope someone can provide input regarding this concern! Thanks guys!

Comment: Let me rephrase - yes it's possible looking at the docs. Don't wait around for someone to tell you, the SDK is so simple just prototype it up quickly and check if it full fills your needs.

Comment: Does the SDK allows you to play any vimeo video or only your own video uploaded to your Vimeo account !?